# Creating similar drop down makes output (innerHTML) undefined (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Heyhey,
I want 2 drop downs with similar content. Version1 works as long as version2 does not exist. As soon as I include version2, only the output of version2 is recognized correctly and the output of version1 is shown as "undefined". Can anyone help me?

````
Version1
*html
<select id="Store">
  <option value="noSelection">Snippet</option>
  <option value="test1">Test1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>

<span id="Adress"></span>

*script
var Store = document.getElementById("Store"),
Adress = document.getElementById("Adress"),
stores = {
  noSelection: "",
  Test1: "Test1",
  Test2: "Test2",
}```

Store.onchange = function(){
snippetMobile.innerHTML = stores[this.value];
}



Version2
*html
<select id="Gas">
  <option value="noSelection">Snippet</option>
  <option value="test1">Test1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>

<span id="Number"></span>

*script
var Gas = document.getElementById("Gas"),
Number = document.getElementById("Number"),
stores = {
  noSelection: "",
  Test3: "Test3",
  Test4: "Test4",
}

Gas.onchange = function(){
Number.innerHTML = stores[this.value];
}
````

Comment: as i see **snippetMobile**  not initialized nowhere. try >>  `Adress.innerHTML = stores[this.value];`

Comment: You share stores too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stores` variable in version 2 will override the initial scope variable. As observed in your example, `"test3"` and `"test4"` is not in use hence no point having them in `stores` object.

Also case of `"T"` in the example does not match with the case of value in `<select>`

Also `snippetMobile` is never defined, I assume you are referring to `Adress` to display the selected option hence I have made those changes.

```js
var Store = document.getElementById("Store"),
  Adress = document.getElementById("Adress"),
  stores = {
    noSelection: "",
    test1: "Test1",
    test2: "Test2",
    test3: "Test3",
    test4: "Test4",
  }

Store.onchange = function() {
  Adress.innerHTML = stores[this.value];
}
var Gas = document.getElementById("Gas"),
  Number = document.getElementById("Number");

Gas.onchange = function() {
  Number.innerHTML = stores[this.value];
}
```

```html
<select id="Store">
  <option value="noSelection">Snippet</option>
  <option value="test1">Test1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>

<span id="Adress"></span>
<select id="Gas">
  <option value="noSelection">Snippet</option>
  <option value="test1">Test1</option>
  <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>

<span id="Number"></span>
```